# I want to create a graduated arc with measurement label with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

Please help me to give a clue to how to create a arc-like diagram with tikz.
I have tried using the following approach but I can not move on

```
    \documentclass[border=4mm]{standalone}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %for arc and angles
    \usetikzlibrary{calc, angles}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[H]
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \iangle in {35,45,55,70,80,90,105,115,130};
    \draw[green] ([shift={(0,0)}]145:1) arc[radius=9,start angle=30,end 
    angle= 150];
    \draw (0.3,0) arc (0:30:0.3) node at (15:0.5) {$\varphi$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Caption1}
    \label{fig3}
    \end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

I want to reproduce the picture I attached here[image]

Answer (score 6):

While you are waiting for some TikZ guidance, here's an effort in [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html), showing off a few features of the loop structures and the inline `if..fi` construction and what you can do with `suffix` variables.  I enjoyed having a go at this one, I hope it's useful at least as an example of what could be done.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
    path C, C'; 
    C = subpath(2,0) of fullcircle rotated 45 scaled 640;
    C' = C scaled 1.02;
    numeric p[];
    p1    = 1/8;
    p2    = 2/8;
    p3    = 3/8;
    p.i   = 5/8;
    p.ii  = 6/8;
    p.iii = 7/8;
    p.n   = 9/8;
    p.l  = 10/8;
    p.zz = 13/8;

    for i=  1/64 step 1/64 until   3/64: drawdot point i of C' withpen pencircle scaled 1; endfor
    for i= 29/64 step 1/64 until  35/64: drawdot point i of C' withpen pencircle scaled 1; endfor
    for i= 61/64 step 1/64 until  67/64: drawdot point i of C' withpen pencircle scaled 1; endfor
    for i= 89/64 step 1/64 until  95/64: drawdot point i of C' withpen pencircle scaled 1; endfor
    for i=116/64 step 1/64 until 119/64: drawdot point i of C' withpen pencircle scaled 1; endfor

    forsuffixes $=1,2,3,i,ii,iii,n,l,zz:
        draw point p$ of C -- point p$ of C' withcolor 2/3 blue;
        label.top("$X_{" & 
            if     str $ = "ii" : "i+1" 
            elseif str $ = "iii": "i+2" 
            elseif str $ = "zz" : "n+l-1" 
            else: str $ fi
        & "}$", point 1 of C') rotated (45-45*p$);
    endfor

    draw C;

    vardef mark(suffix a, b)(expr s, T) =
        save arc; path arc;
        arc = subpath(p.a, p.b) of C scaled s;
        interim ahangle  := 180; interim ahlength := 5;
        drawdblarrow arc withcolor 2/3 green;

        save pp; picture pp; 
        pp = thelabel(T rotated angle direction 1/2 of arc, point 1/2 of arc);
        unfill bbox pp; draw pp;
    enddef;

    mark(1, i, 0.95, textext("$Y_1$"));
    mark(2, ii, 0.90, textext("$Y_2$"));
    mark(3, iii, 0.85, textext("$Y_3$"));
    mark(n, zz, 0.95, textext("$Y_n$"));

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

This is wrapped up in `luamblib` so compile with `lualatex`, or adapt for plain MP, or `gmp` package etc.

### Notes

- I've defined `C` to be a quarter of the usual `fullcircle` path, rotated 45° and reversed so that it runs clockwise, or from left to right as you look at it.
- This path `C` is two units of "time" long.  So point 0 is the left hand end, point 1 is the middle, and point 2 is the right hand end.
- Path `C'` is the same but scaled up a little bit.
- The `p[]` part defined various times that we want along `C`.
- The first five loops draw some dots.  If this was really clever I would have related all these values to those I've just defined in `p...`, but it's not.  The lines of dots might look straight, but actually they are curved.
- Most of the hard work is then done by the `forsuffixes` loop.  It's convenient that you can use letters and numbers as suffixes, but there are limitations, so you can't have a whole expression as a suffix.  So in order to get "i+1" etc, I've resorted to a little inline `if` to test them.  Not very flexible, but good enough for a few of them.
- The green lines are then done with the inline `mark` macro.

Comment: Thanks, it is not running on my platform. I use miktex with texstudio. May be I have not loaded enough packages. please run it again at your end and see what you can do for me to make it run hear

Comment: As I said at the top of the notes, you need to use lualatex to compile this one. See the help in texstudio for how to change engine.

Comment: Yes, I have found the help out some how, by placing "% !TeX program = lualatex" at the beginning of the code just as a comment

Answer (score 4):

In TikZ for arcs the start point is given with `\draw`, not the center. But for concentric arcs, the center must be known. For this a `\coordinate` is used and from there the start points of the arcs are calculated with the start angle and the radius. The same method can be used to calculate start and end points of the radial lines.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (C) at (0,0);     % center point
\draw[red] (C) circle (0.05) node[right] {center}; % mark the center, just to show it
\draw (C) arc (30:60:1) node[above] {arc starting at center}; % arc starting at center, just to show how an arc is drawn an arc is drawn
\draw[green] ($(C) + (30:9)$) arc (30:150:9); % main arc
% partial arcs and radial lines
\draw ($(C) + (120:8.6)$) arc (120:90:8.6) node[fill=white,inner sep=1pt] at (105:8.6) {$\varphi$};
\draw ($(C) + (120:8.5)$) -- ($(C) + (120:9)$);
\draw ($(C) + (90:8.5)$) -- ($(C) + (90:9)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

This can be automated in an `\foreach` loop. Here the start angel, the end angle, and the distance to the main arc is given in the list. Other values are then calculated. For the labels the `count` option of `\foreach` is used.

[image]

The complete code:

```
\documentclass[border=4mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%for arc and angles
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (C) at (0,0);        % center point
\pgfmathsetmacro\overlength{0.1} % additional length for radial lines
\pgfmathsetmacro\ticklength{0.2} % length of radial tick
\pgfmathsetmacro\mainradius{9}
\draw[green] ($(C) + (30:9)$) arc (30:150:\mainradius); % main arc

\foreach \startangle/\endangle/\dist[count=\cnt] in {120/90/0.4,110/80/0.8}{%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\midangle{(\startangle+\endangle)/2} % angle for node
    \pgfmathsetmacro\arcradius{\mainradius-\dist}       % radius
    \pgfmathsetmacro\startline{\arcradius-\overlength}  % start of radial line
    \pgfmathsetmacro\tickend{\mainradius+\ticklength}   % end of tick
    \pgfmathsetmacro\cnti{int(\cnt-1)}                  % count for $X_l$
    % arc
    \draw ($(C) + (\startangle:\arcradius)$) arc (\startangle:\endangle:\arcradius) node[fill=white,inner sep=1pt] at (\midangle:\arcradius) {$Y_\cnt$};
    % radial lines
    \draw ($(C) + (\startangle:\startline)$) -- ($(C) + (\startangle:\mainradius)$);
    \draw ($(C) + (\endangle:\startline)$)   -- ($(C) + (\endangle:\mainradius)$);
    % ticks
    \draw ($(C) + (\startangle:\mainradius)$) -- ($(C) + (\startangle:\tickend)$) node[above] {$X_\cnt$};
    \draw ($(C) + (\endangle:\mainradius)$)   -- ($(C) + (\endangle:\tickend)$) node[above] {$\ifnum\cnti=0\relax X_{l}\else X_{l+\cnti}\fi$};
}
% drawing dots
\draw[loosely dotted, very thick] ($(C) + (105:9.15)$) arc (105:95:9.15);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```